# win32gui.GetCursorPos() returning position 80% smaller than expected position

Tags: python, python-2.7, winapi

I created a small Python script some time ago to bound my cursor position to a given bbox so my cursor doesn't go floating off over my second monitor while playing poorly made games. When I made it I was using a 1080p monitor and it worked no issues there, however after just recently changing my monitors out for 1440p and updating the bbox I found the returned positions are off very consistently.

Every position returned from win32gui.GetCursorPos() is 80% smaller than what I'm expecting. Top left corner returns (0,0) as expected, bottom right of first monitor is (2047,1151), and bottom right of second monitor is (4095,1151), 80% smaller than the actual screen sizes (2560x1440p for both screens).

Source Code-

```
import time, win32api, win32con, win32gui

prev_len = 0 # Used for printr()

def printr( msg):
    '''Print that automatically resets previous message'''
    global prev_len
    print '\r', ' '*prev_len, '\r', msg,
    prev_len = len( msg)

def get_pos():
    return win32gui.GetCursorPos()

def set_pos(( x, y)):
    win32api.SetCursorPos( (int(x),int(y)))

def key_pressed( key):
    return win32api.GetAsyncKeyState( key)

def combo_pressed( key_li):
    for key in key_li:
        if key_pressed( key) == False:
            return False
    return True

def check_pos( pos, bbox):
    check_more, check_less = bbox
    x_pos, y_pos = pos
    if check_more[0] > x_pos:
        x_pos = check_more[0]
    elif x_pos > check_less[0]:
        x_pos = check_less[0]
    else:
        pass
    if check_more[1] > y_pos:
        y_pos = check_more[1]
    elif y_pos > check_less[1]:
        y_pos = check_less[1]
    else:
        pass
    return (x_pos, y_pos)

KEY_COMBO = [
    win32con.VK_LCONTROL,
    win32con.VK_LSHIFT,
    ord( 'P')]
SLEEP_TIME = 0.05

SCREEN_SIZE = (2560, 1440)
CENTER_SCREEN = tuple([ x/2 for x in SCREEN_SIZE])

SCREEN_BBOX = ((0,0),SCREEN_SIZE)

lock_mode = False # Toggle whether or not position is currently locked to bbox
allow_toggle = True # Make sure toggle doesn't happen multiple times per key combo

print "Payday 2 Utility to make sure cursor is locked onto primary screen during play.\n"
printr( "Lock Disabled.")

while True:
    time.sleep( SLEEP_TIME)
    if combo_pressed( KEY_COMBO) and allow_toggle:
        lock_mode = not lock_mode
        allow_toggle = False

        if lock_mode:
            printr( "Lock Enabled. Cursor bound to: (%s,%s)" % SCREEN_BBOX)
        else:
            printr( "Lock Disabled.")
    else:
        allow_toggle = True
    #printr( get_pos())
    if lock_mode:
        set_pos( check_pos( get_pos(), SCREEN_BBOX) )
```

I'm running Windows 8.1 64bit, source code is above but these are the only relevant bits:

`import win32gui
while True:
    time.sleep( SLEEP_TIME)
    print win32gui.GetCursorPos()`

which currently returns cursor positions smaller than expected.

Comment: call `ctypes.windll.Shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)`

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. What does that do?

Comment: Read about DPI awareness